# Automated Focusing in edit mode

Tags: edit-mode

Is there a way, a setting for blender to put the focus on the current selection of vertices you edit in edit mode, **automaticaly**? Pivoting around the selection is dizzying if you don't  continuously press the point key (.) just to focus on it, which i think is so redundant. but i don't want it also zooming in TOO close in your face every time like when blender focuses on things.

Comment: Please don't ask the same question twice. If you have something further to add to your original question you can use the 'edit' button below it.

Comment: ok, should i delete this one then?
this question is a more specific one thou (one area only), while the first was more in general (different areas)

Comment: @RayMairlot is there a countdown timer here(blenderstack) to know when can i ask  a question again?

Comment: Personally, I suggest deleting this one and keeping the other one. You're not meant to re-ask a question at all. You can read more about that here: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/473/can-i-re-ask-a-question-if-it-hasnt-been-answered

Comment: ok, but only after i get a clear answer to either